# Can 'that' be used instead of ' since' and 'as'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in Cambridge dictionary - 
**I never get to see her now that she works somewhere else** 
Does "that" mean "since" here ?
I checked a few learner's dictionaries but could not find its meaning in this context.

Comment: Yes (or "as a consequence of", or "because"), but it's not just "that" which conveys that particular meaning but the whole expression "now that she works somewhere else". Cf. "I never get to see her because she now works somewhere else". Note that in your example, "that" is omissible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"now that" is a unit. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/now-that), it is a conjunction. It combines time and reason. The sentence:

> I never get to see her now that she works somewhere else.

could be broken down as follows:

> **Now** she works somewhere else **and as a result** I never get to see her.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "now that" is a "unit" (i.e. a compound coordinator) , since in many instances "that" is omissible. The preposition "now" governs the content clause, so in "I never get to see her [now that she works somewhere else] the bracketed element is a preposition phrase headed by the prep "now" with the content clause "that she works somewhere else" as its complement.

Comment: @BillJ Some grammarians call "now that" (as well as other similar linkers) a multi-word or phrasal subordinating conjunction. Please see here, at the top of the page: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=zLMaCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&dq=%22now+that%22+subordinating+conjunction&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW7qWPuaLYAhVMfZAKHTJsBCsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22now%20that%22%20subordinating%20conjunction&f=false Never heard of "now" as a preposition...

Comment: It can't be a 'compound conjunction' since "that" is very often omissible, as it is in the OP's example.

Comment: @BillJ I see your point. We could say that, when present, "that" attaches to "now". One thing is clear: "that" does not have a separate meaning and needs "now" before it to work as a linking word expressing reason.

Comment: Yes, "now" governs the content clause -- unlike "that", it is not omissible. Btw, do you have a copy of CGEL?

Comment: @BillJ I do. You want me to check it?

Comment: Have a look at 4.8 on p971, where it is all explained.

Comment: @BillJ Very interesting. Thank you. It's funny to find "now" among other subordinators of verbal origin like *provided, given, considering, assuming*, where "that" clearly introduces a content clause. But I will not argue with Huddleston & Pullum!

Comment: I mistakenly posted my comment in answer section.

Comment: @Gustavson It's not saying they are subordinators, but prepositions.

Comment: @BillJ I know. Anyway, prepositions are subordinating elements.